# Facet Searching Sunspot/Solr Not Faceting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

So my Database is set up with a :bar, :day, :deal.  Day is in the form of Monday, Tuesday...

I want to facet on :day, but no facets will show up.  Does anything stick out that I have done wrong?

h_contoller

```
def index
  @search = Happy.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    facet(:day)
    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 550
  end
  @happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id)).page(params[:page])
end
```

model

```
searchable do
  text :name, :boost => 5
  text :day, :boost => 10
  string :day   
end
```

view

```
<% @search.facet(:day).rows.each do |facet| %>
  <p><%= puts "Author #{facet.value} has #{facet.count} pizza posts!" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model You have the field day defined twice:

```
text :day, :boost => 10
string :day
```

Facets should be applied on string not text.
You just need to rename one of the field in your model :

```
text :day, :boost => 10
string :day_str do
  day
end
```

end then do the facet on it :

```
def index
  @search = Happy.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    facet(:day_str)
    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 550
  end
  @happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id)).page(params[:page])
end
```

and in the view:

```
<% @search.facet(:day_str).rows.each do |facet| %>
  <p><%= puts "Author #{facet.value} has #{facet.count} pizza posts!" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You may want to check in the solr web console what are the values stored, and what is your solr query returning.